# VB.net Login Attempts Counter

Tags: vb.net

Alright I think this is pretty self explanatory and the easiest thing ever.  But I can't get this to work, for some reason.

```
Partial Class IntroductionPage 'CodeBehind for an ASPX Web page.
    Public NumberOfAttempts As Integer = 0
    Protected Sub PinButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PinButton.Click
        NumberOfAttempts = NumberOfAttempts + 1
        'Query the database for the password, etc (omitted)...
        If (x = 1 And NumberOfAttempts <= 10) Then
            ' Then Login the user successfully. (omitted)
        Else
            ' The Pin was not found in the DB.  We should throw error and make the validation label visible. (omitted)
        End If
        If (NumberOfAttempts > 10) Then
            AttemptsErrorMessage.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

In testing this I simply try to login with an incorrect password 10 times, and yet the label does not show up.  I tried different passwords each time.  Also, even after 10 attempts, I tried a valid password and then the program still logined the user successfully (which is shouldn't have, based on the logic of the first if statement).

I tried to follow this resource, as well as a few others which described exactly the same process: [How to count login attempts Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770824/how-to-count-login-attempts-visual-basic).  **Edit/Note for future viewers**: Essentially, it seems that that resource may just be incorrect for ASPX web pages.  At least, I couldn't get it to work that way.  Please see answers and comments below.

Comment: where/how is `NumberOfAttempts` defined? where/how is `x` defined, where did it come from? have you set a Breakpoint to see what part is not working as expected?

Comment: You sure the label has text in it and isn't hidden behind some other control?

Comment: Is this a web page or a windows form?

Comment: Sorry Plutonix, I guess I should have specified.  That has to do with my login check function call which I omitted.  It returns 1 if the login succeeded.  That part of the code works great as expected.

Comment: I really don't understand why this is a downvote question.  This is a simple and self explanatory programming related question.

Comment: @Musicode, yes, it should not be a down vote question but as Plutonix said, edit the question and write down the relevant function of login check. I think it would be easy to make out with that.

Comment: @Rick S This is located in the codebehind of an aspx web page.

Comment: If it's part of the code behind, my guess is that the counter is getting reset to zero every time you do a postback - `Public NumberOfAttempts As Integer = 0`.  Try putting the value of `NumberOfAttempts` in `Session`.

Comment: @Tim That was one of my thoughts as well, that perhaps I should define this as a global variable or as a Session variable.  I wanted to avoid using too many Session variables but I will try this now.

Comment: @Musicode - a global variable will still get reset per your code in a web app.  You'll need to use `Session` or some other persistent store mechanism to keep track.

Comment: I like the phrase "persistent store mechanism".

Comment: @Musicode - Regarding the answer you linked to, that was for a WinForms application, so the answer was correct, but only for WinForms.  In a WinForm, the class for the form is constructed and then events are raised (and handled) without recreating the form.  In a WebForm, as you know, the page is recreated every time a full postback occurs, which is why the class level variable approach didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application is a web application, so the value of the counter is being reset to 0 every time you post back by this line:

```
Public NumberOfAttempts As Integer = 0
```

You need to keep track of the number of attempts in `Session` (or some other persistent store mechanism).  Try something like this:

```
Partial Class IntroductionPage 'CodeBehind for an ASPX Web page.

    Protected Sub PinButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PinButton.Click

        Dim NumberOfAttempts As Integer

        If Session("NumberOfAttempts") Is Not Nothing Then        
            NumberOfAttempts = CInt(Session("NumberOfAttempts"))
        End If

        'Query the database for the password, etc (omitted)..

        NumberOfAttempts = NumberOfAttempts + 1
        Session("NumberOfAttempts") = NumberOfAttempts

        If (x = 1 And NumberOfAttempts <= 10) Then
            ' Then Login the user successfully. (omitted)
        Else
            ' The Pin was not found in the DB.  We should throw error and make the validation label visible. (omitted)
        End If

        If (NumberOfAttempts > 10) Then
            AttemptsErrorMessage.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The key part in the code above is checking to see if Session has a value and getting that value (it will be 0 by default), then incrementing that count (and putting it back in Session) each time the user tries to log in.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a new page each time you do a post on the page.  NumberOfAttempts will never reach a value of 10.  You will need to store the value in a Session variable, a cookie, database, or some other place you have access to and load it each time.

See this MSDN page for additional information on the page life cycle.  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Here is an article on MSDN talking about options you have in manageing state with ASP.NET.  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Using a cookie would probably not be the best option, since this is tracking login attempts and the client can change the cookie value, unless the cookie was encrypted/signed by the server.